# How do I prepare my Ubuntu SSD for a windows install after it has been reformated?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have an extra SSD which I had previously installed Ubuntu on for fun and after years of little use decided to switch back to windows to use as a OS only hard drive after my main windows HD has become slow. I also have 2 internal hard drives, one with windows installed and one used for storage. I have run into some issues that may be my own fault regarding the new windows install on the SSD. I used windows disc formatting tool to wipe the SSD of Ubuntu and format it as NTSF. I then installed a copy of windows on the SSD using my internal hard drive windows OS. After the install finished and a few days of updates and use have gone by I start getting blue screens and eventually an error: grub rescue error: unknown file system. I decided to unplug by 2 internal hard drives and reinstall windows. Everything worked and the install ran fine until I plugged them back in. Now upon boot I get an option to boot into Ubuntu(something to do with the grub?) or windows. If I select Windows the start up stalls on the Windows loading screen for a long enough time that I haven't waited for it to finish.

I assume the issue has something to do with the SSD retaining something from the old Ubuntu install, but I am a novice with linux and don't really know where to start.

I have the files from the internal hard drive with the windows install backed up and am fine with wiping it once I can load the SSD copy of windows if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It has NOTHING to do with your SSD retaining something from old install. Since you have formatted the drive the usable data on it is gone period. From what i get, its the old bootloaders and their redundant entries which you have encountered.

Firstly, do take note of what disk you boot from in your bios.

Next, to correct your bootloader your should run(from an ubuntu installation),

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

replace `/dev/sda` with your disk

If you want to remove grub completely with windows bootloader you must run startup repair in windows or install easybcd and crrect it from there

Comment: I do not have Ubuntu installed anymore and like I mentioned in the first post, my Windows copy on my internal HD gets stuck on startup and the SSD thinks Ubuntu is installed(but it is not). I attempted a startup repair on the SSD getting the message 'Windows can not fix the problem. Send information to Microsoft or Don't Send'. Since I have done it before I'm sure I can install a fresh copy of windows on the SSD that I can work from. In this case what I am understanding is that I need to remove grub completely to avoid getting this error again. Would that mean using easybcd as you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, easybcd will be able to edit your mbr,  however i would recommend to try running windows startup repair as it also restores windows bootloader. If you are unable to enter windows, press f8 on startup(after bios screen but before windows gets booted) it will show you advanced options for windows. Also check the wiki, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader